# How to use 'fn', which generates a function that calculates the golden ratio

Tags: python

Using 'fn'  generate function that calculates golden ratio approximation.

final formula:
1 + 1 / (1 + 1 / (1 + 1 / (...)))

some results:

```
golden_ratio(0) = 1
golden_ratio(1) = 2
golden_ratio(2) = 1.5
golden_ratio(100) = 1.6180...
```

Function signature: def golden_ratio (n), where 'n' is number of invocations (and number of terms in continued fraction)

In general, I did the task, here are the errors:

1. Function signature: def golden_ratio (n), where 'n' is number of invocations (and number of terms in continued fraction).
2. print (w / q)
   The results are incorrect.

With n = 1000, it displays about 1.62, as it should.

```
golden_ratio(0) = 1
golden_ratio(1) = 2
golden_ratio(2) = 1.5
```

but with these n - it does not work.  Help me please(

this is my code:

```
n=1000
def fn(f,n):
    def wrap(*arg):
        for _ in range(n):
            arg = f(*arg)
        return arg
    return wrap
 
def fib(q, w):
    q, w = w, q + w
    return q, w
 
f3 = fn(fib, n)
q, w = f3(0, 1)
# gold section
print(w / q)
```

Comment: ??? With n=0 it throws a `division by zero error`, and for all other values it seems to calculate the correct approximation?

Comment: If you are doing this for some kind of online assignment, maybe the problem is that you didn't actually write a function named `golden_ratio` that accepts the number of invocations as a parameter? But the code as shown does the expected calculations, and the `print` statement at the end shows me `1.618033988749895`.

Comment: I was mistaken, when n-1000 gives the correct value, n = 0 (division by zero error), but should 1, as in the example

Comment: and other.... 1 and 2

Comment: Oh. Well, think more carefully about what the initial arguments for `f3` should be.

Comment: @Karl Knechtel but 1.61 only with n = 1000, but for other n, as in the example it considers incorrect

Comment: @Karl Knechtel   As for the function, as I understand it, it just needs to be called differently)

Comment: I repeat: Oh. *Well, think more carefully about what the initial arguments for f3 should be.* The bigger `n` is, the more accurate it gets, so of course you don't notice when you get the result for n=1000 that you're supposed to get for n=999, but you do notice when you get the result for n=1 that you're supposed to get for n=0 (or when you get an error for n=0).

Comment: As opposed to many other first posters on StackOverflow your first question turned out to be pretty well-formulated. As for your problem – never underestimate the power of a debugger to unterstand what's actually happening. And most likely you'll find then the solution yourself. Have a look at [How to debug small programs](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs) referenced in [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: Don't forget to accept an answer for your question if it answers your question.

Comment: n=0 and n=1 cases are special and you should treat them different in the code. This is true for every golden ratio calculation, not just your code.

Answer (score 2):

When you defined the Fibonacci function

```
def fib(q, w):
    q, w = w, q + w
    return q, w
```

you chose its typical initial values `0` and `1` in `q, w = f3(0, 1)` assuming that the function's first invocation results into `q = 1, w = 1` leading to `w / q = 1.0`.

#### Your problem

Given `n = 0` and your code, ***your problem is that `fib(0, 1)` isn't executed by `arg = f(*arg)`*** because your for-loop `for _ in range(n):` doesn't execute (`n = 0 -> range(0, 0)`)!

The following `return arg` then returns your initial function arguments `0, 1` (unchanged) back which results into `q = 0, w = 1`. And thus you get a division by zero error.

#### Possible solutions

There are three possible solutions to fix your code.

1. Ensure that your for-loop executes for your very first iteration being `n = 0` by changing `for _ in range(n):` to `for _ in range(n+1):`
2. ***or*** adapt your initial function arguments `f3(0, 1)` to be the expected result `1, 1` as it's being returned by `return arg` by changing `q, w = f3(0, 1)` to `q, w = f3(1, 1)`
3. ***or*** change your mind that `golden_ratio(0)` is actually the *first iteration of your approximation* and therefore you iteration variable `n` is 1-based instead of 0-based, i.e. enforce in your code `n >= 1`.

Picking the first option, you get

```
n=0
def fn(f,n):
    def wrap(*arg):
        for _ in range(n+1): # <-- fix for-loop
            arg = f(*arg)
        return arg
    return wrap
 
def fib(q, w):
    q, w = w, q + w
    return q, w
 
f3 = fn(fib, n)
q, w = f3(0, 1)
# gold section
print(w / q)
```

which gives you

```
golden_ratio(0)    = 1.0
golden_ratio(1)    = 2.0
golden_ratio(2)    = 1.5
golden_ratio(3)    = 1.6666666666666667
golden_ratio(4)    = 1.6
golden_ratio(5)    = 1.625
...
golden_ratio(100)  = 1.618033988749895
...
golden_ratio(999)  = 1.618033988749895
golden_ratio(1000) = 1.618033988749895
```